# Showing error that platform name cannot be resolved even i added all the required files regarding to it

Tags: eclipse, appium

The below image shows my question in detail:

[image]

it works when client version is changed to 5 beta but the tapOptions doesn't work

when client is changed to 7.0.0 tapOptions works but platform name cannot be resolved

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images of your code, the website allows for markdown so you can paste the code here and have it easy to read if formatted correctly. And people can copy and paste and more easily help you.

Comment: Deprecated [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/commit/4ae09506fa56d1d6fa74e94ae2204aef3da2f958#diff-7ffa4c71ce252408a910625b7ab34f4eR111), removed [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/commit/18552913bdd6b9025d51e4e4a1b74509d80b0797#diff-98a20c74383e6e44050d14ded4d0f7ecL37): _"This flag IS deprecated since appium node 1.5.x. It will be removed in the next release. Be careful."_

Answer (score 0):

Try [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/). They have plugins for [Eclipse](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio-eclipse/)/[IntelliJ](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio-intellij/) which sets up the entire framework for you with integration with TestNG,JUnit, etc. You can just code the test logic and run.
Check out their documentation for [Eclipse](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio+for+Eclipse), [IntelliJ](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio+for+IntelliJ) and [Appium Studio](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio) standalone application.